# Builtin USB Webcam gets recognized as Keyboard?

Tags: usb, xorg, 17.04, webcam

I installed some Ubuntu on my Eee Pc a few years ago and the webcam did not work. That didn't really bother me, cause I didn't use it anyway.
Recently, I updated to Ubuntu 17.04 (as in formatted the Ubuntu partition and freshly installed). While troubleshooting some other problems I visited `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and noticed following section:

```
[   775.333] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB2.0 UVC VGA WebCam (/dev/input/event8)
[   775.334] (**) USB2.0 UVC VGA WebCam: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   775.334] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'USB2.0 UVC VGA WebCam'
[   775.334] (**) USB2.0 UVC VGA WebCam: always reports core events
[   775.334] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[   775.334] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   775.336] (II) input device 'USB2.0 UVC VGA WebCam', /dev/input/event8 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   775.336] (II) input device 'USB2.0 UVC VGA WebCam', /dev/input/event8 is a keyboard
[   775.368] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input9/event8"
[   775.368] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB2.0 UVC VGA WebCam" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[   775.368] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   775.368] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[   775.371] (II) input device 'USB2.0 UVC VGA WebCam', /dev/input/event8 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   775.371] (II) input device 'USB2.0 UVC VGA WebCam', /dev/input/event8 is a keyboard
[   775.374] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[   775.374] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   775.374] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[   775.374] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
```

I have no idea why Xorg is even handling USB/Input devices (isn't it a *display* server ?),
but the main question is:
**How can I stop Ubuntu/Xorg from trying to use my poor Webcam as a keyboard and start using it as an actual Webcam?**

Comment: You could probably add a udev rule to prevent it from claiming it

Comment: Could add the output of `lsusb; lsusb -t` also full `dmesg` where it shows vid/pid.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @You'reAGitForNotUsingGit can you help me here, how do you do that with udev rule?

Answer (score 6):

A `udev` rule can be set to prevent a USB device from loading a driver, which should have the intended effect of disabling part of a device while leaving other functions operational.

Here's how you can do it:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Determine the manufacturer and device ID via `lsusb` (for PCI devices, you can use `lspci`):

   ```
   sudo lsusb
   ```

   You will likely see an output similar to this:

   ```
   ...
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b448 TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB
   ...
   ```

   Note the manufacturer ID (eg. `04f2`) and product ID (eg. `b448`). These will be important later.
2. Determine the driver(s) that the device requires via `udevadm`:

   ```
   udevadm info -a /dev/input/by-id/*
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** You will need to sift through the `input` devices to find your camera. Alternatively, if you look at the contents of `/dev/input/by-id`, you may spot your camera. Then you can issue a more specific command, like `udevadm info -a /dev/input/by-id/*Camera*`.</sup>

   You will likely see a great deal of information that starts like this:

   ```
   looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
        KERNELS=="usb3"
        SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
        DRIVERS=="usb"
   ```

   You want to pay attention to `DRIVERS` for the USB device that is your camera. There will be a line that may say `uvcvideo` and another that'll say something like `libinput`, which is incorrect.
3. Create a `udev` rule file:

   ```
   sudo {text editor of choice} /etc/udev/rules.d/90-blacklist-webcam-keyboard.rules
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{text editor of choice}` with your text editor of choice. I used to put `vi` in there, as that's what a neckbeard like me uses. However, a lot of those posts would get edited to replace `vi` with `gedit` or some other newfangled thing. TLDR; use what works for you.</sup>

   In that file, record the driver, manufacturer ID, and product ID in a format like this:

   ```
   # Not a keyboard!
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVER=="libinput", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="b448", ATTR{authorized}="0"
   ```
4. Reboot.

   <sup>**Note:** If the camera were a USB device that could be disconnected and reconnected, you could simply reload the `udev` rules with a `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` and re-connect the device. However, as it's built-in, a reboot is the simplest option without getting into complicated hardware API commands.</sup>
5. Test your camera.

If everything works as expected, your camera will now be seen only as a camera. There may be a line in the `syslog` that says the keyboard is not authorised, but that will be that.